# JDBC Sqlite - Insert Query is not working when I run my project through Jenkins

Tags: java, sqlite, jenkins, jdbc

Jenkins is not allowing me to insert data in case my build is fail or pass. 
I am using SQLite, Java, JDBC. 
The same build is working fine on my local machine data is inserted successfully.

Here is the code which includes my connection, insert query and dependency file

Dependency file --

```
        sqlite-jdbc--    3.7.2
```

Code which includes connection and the insert query,

```
public static void finalinsert() throws SQLException {
     DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.sqlite.JDBC());
     Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/test/resources/DataBase/DailyStatus.sqlite");

 c.setAutoCommit(false);
 try {
    // PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement("");

     File file = new File("src/test/resources/DataBase/DailyStatus.sqlite");

     if(file.exists()){
         System.out.println("Is Execute allow : " + file.canExecute());
         System.out.println("Is Write allow : " + file.canWrite());
         System.out.println("Is Read allow : " + file.canRead());
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("NOT found");
     }

     file.setExecutable(true);
     file.setReadable(true);
     file.setWritable(true);

         System.out.println("Is Execute allow : " + file.canExecute());
         System.out.println("Is Write allow : " + file.canWrite());
         System.out.println("Is Read allow : " + file.canRead());

         PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement("insert into Report(Status,Date) values('Fail','" + java.time.LocalDateTime.now() + "')");
         try {

             p.executeUpdate();
             System.out.println("out");
             c.commit();
             p.close();

         } finally {
             p.close();
         }

     } finally {
         c.close();
     }
     return;
 }
```

I also tried with .db file too but did not work. also tried with Recordset too.

I am using git to run code from Jenkins.

Please let me know what things I missed or can be improved so that insert query starts working at Jenkins.

Comment: Had the same kind of issue last week, I found out that the directory containing the db file must be writable too, under ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The problem is with the path, when run, it probably can't find `src/test/resources/DataBase/DailyStatus.sqlite`. Your source paths are usually not the paths at runtime.

Comment: Hi Eby, Thanks for your quick reply ...as per your suggestion I updated the path " scr/DailyStatus.sqlite " but still it does not worked. Also gave the permission to the folder and the database file  but it remains the same.

I am also using select query which is working fine 
I don't know what the problem with insert query even I write the whole code under exception handling still no error appears.